# How to get the highest value from a sum of values in php that is not in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Good Day, I have a table in php that sums up the values that is stored in MySQL.

MySQL table:

```
USER 1:
crit_1 = 75
crit_2 = 75
USER2:
crit_1 = 100
crit_2 = 100
```

My PHP goes like this:

```
$crit_1 = $row["crit_1"];
$crit_2 = $row["crit_2"];
$sum = ($crit_1 + $crit_2);
$total = number_format ($sum / 2, 2, '.',' ');
```

and here is my HTML

```
<th><strong>Score from Crit_1</strong></th>
<th><strong>Score from Crit_2</strong></th>
<th><strong>TOTAL SCORE OF crit_1 and crit_2</strong></th>

<td align="center"><?php echo $crit_1; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $crit_2; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $total; ?></td>
```

Now this sums up crit_1 and crit_2 that is stored in MySQL using PHP. What I wanted to do is to get the highest value from the third column which is `$total` and place it in another column or another textbox somewhere (any would do)

What I tried so far is.

```
    $value = max($total);
    $key = array_search($value, $total);

<td align="center"><?php echo (max($total)); ?></td>
```

but I am having this error:

```
max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array
```

So I guess my real question is, How can I convert $total into an array of string, so I can get the highest value. Or if you do have any other approach to my problem. THanks.

Comment: where's the mysql for this, or is this a "write it for you" type of question? If that tag is irrelevant, it should be removed.

Comment: *My Query goes like this* That's not a query, that's PHP code.

Comment: I have included MySQL table example. I just wanted to know if I am on the right path but need to do something, or I need to do something else rather that max().

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: wanted to get the highest value from column `TOTAL score of crit_1 and crit_2` and show it another textbox or in another column

Comment: Since `$total` is being created in php, most likely in a loop over your mysql rows, you need to add each `$total` to an array, is. `$totals[] = $total;`. Then after your loop you can do `$value = max($totals);`

Comment: This actually worked. Thanks for this SEAN. So I get it. In order for me to array the values is to add a variable `$totals[]`. Thanks again.

Comment: One last question though, How can I echo the entire row that has the highest value? not only the score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a `array` named `$max_total` and each time during `looping` `insert` $total `value` in it. Then use `max()` `fuction` to get max.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$mysql_database = "a";

$max_total = array();
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die ("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
$result =  mysqli_query($conn, "select * from reg")or die("error");
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><th><strong>Score from Crit_1</strong></th>
<th><strong>Score from Crit_2</strong></th>
<th><strong>TOTAL SCORE OF crit_1 and crit_2</strong></th></tr>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $max_total[] = $row['crit_1'] + $row['crit_2'];
    echo '<tr><td align="center">'.$row['crit_1'].'</td><td align="center">'.$row['crit_2'].'</td><td align="center">'.($row['crit_1'] + $row['crit_2']).'</td></tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
echo(max($max_total));
```

Change `table name` and `database name` according to yours.

for more info about please raed http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

Comment: This Worked to. But It is the same as Sean's comment. Thanks again

Comment: One last question though, How can I echo the entire row that has the highest value? not only the score.

Comment: very simple if you have primary id in your table then when creation your $max_total create primary id as its key like inside while loop. $max_total[$row['id']] =  $row['crit_1'] + $row['crit_2'];. Then get the id of largest value and by using that id fetch your desired result

Comment: I dont get it. What I did based on your example above is
`$totals[] = $total;
 $value = max($totals);`
and echoed
`<?php echo $value; ?>`
this shows to highest value only. But how can I get the entire row?